# Empfohlene Schreibung von Telefonnummern mit Klammernull

Tags: spelling, numbers

Anlässlich der Erstellung von Visitenkarten für einen kommunalen Betrieb kam hier die Frage auf, ob es Regeln für die Schreibung insbesondere ausländischer Telefonnummern gibt, die man zur Verteidigung einer brauchbaren Typographie gegenüber einer regelgläubigen Bürokratie anführen könnte.

Das Problem: Die Visitenkartenabteilung schlug vor:

> +49(0)511 123-87654

Ich hingegeben finde das Fehlen des Spatiums vor der Klammernull störend und hielte es für normal und schön,

> +49 (0)511 123-87654

zu schreiben.

Die Konsultation eines Regelwerks für geschäftlichen Schriftverkehr (*Karl Wilhelm Henke: Die neue DIN 5008 verständlich erklärt und kommentiert. Winklers, 1. Auflage 2012*) brachte leider nichts, denn der Fall der Klammernull taucht dort gar nicht auf. Man findet dort nur folgende Beispiele für wohlgesetzte Telefonnummern:

> 02921 2345328
>
> 06151 2525-120
>
> +49 6151 3453-12

Andererseits ist die Klammernull so unüblich nicht. Gerade Leute, die sowohl mit in- wie mit ausländischen Geschäftspartnern zu tun haben, verwenden sie gerne, um einerseits die volle Nummer samt Landesvorwahl abgebildet zu haben, andererseits die inländischen Partner daran zu erinnern, beim Weglassen der Landesvorwahl dann eine Null für die Ortsnetzvorwahl vorzuwählen.

Hinweise auf gedruckte oder sonstwie offiziell aussehende Regelwerke würden dafür verwendet, eine möglicherweise widerspenstige Bürokratie auf den Tugendpfad guter Typographie zurückzuführen.

**Nachtrag:**

Es gibt für den fraglichen Betrieb ein Corporate-Design-Handbuch. Dieses äußert sich aber nicht explizit zu dieser Frage. Man kann zwar behaupten, die von mir präferierte Schreibung sei dort implizit empfohlen, da in einigen Beispielen in diesem Handbuch diese Schreibung (und keine andere) beiläufig verwendet wird. In realen Druck-Erzeugnissen dieses Betriebs finden sich jedoch auch Fälle von Spatienverzicht. Ich würde vermuten, dies beruht auf Nachlässigkeit. Das hilft also nicht weiter.

Comment: Die null kann eingentlich, egal ob in Klammer oder nach einem Schrägstrich, komplett weggelassen werden, da auch im Inland stattdessen die +49 vorgewählt werden kann. So gesehen ist die in der Frage genannte schreibweise nach Henke und DIN die richtige.

Comment: @scienceponder    Auch wieder wahr...

Comment: @scienceponder Mit den Schreibweisen kennt sich nicht jeder aus. Der ortliche Anschlussinhaber dessen Nummer mit 49 beginnt freut sich dann über viele falsche Anrufe :-)

Comment: Warum soll überhaupt die (0) mit in die Telefonnummer? Das ist a) verwirrend und b) wie schon von dir geschrieben entgegen DIN5008 und c) ist eine Telefonnummer mit +490XXX per se ungültig. Davon ab auf jeden Fall mit Leerzeichen, da zu lange Zahlenreihen unübersichtlich sind. Aber: warum nicht einfach nachfragen welches Schweinderl die gern hätten ;)

Comment: Wenn du mir zwei Tage Zeit gibst, schaue ich in »Detailtypografie« nach, was Forssman vorschlägt

Comment: @scienceponder An einem Festnetzanschluss kannst du nicht + wählen. Vielleicht klappt es mit 0049, aber deutsche Telefonnummer sind von einem Festnetzanschluss nicht unbedingt unter 0049 erreichbar. Das kann klappen, muss aber nicht.

Comment: @jarnbjo Nein, natürlich nicht. Denn das + ist ein Platzhalter, den der Nutzer eines Telefons durch das jeweils notwendige Zeichen ersetzen muss. Ich zitiere den Artikel *Telefonvorwahl* aus Wikipedia: "Das Plus-Zeichen „+“ muss vom Anrufer durch die jeweils gültige internationale Verkehrsausscheidungsziffer ersetzt werden; zum Beispiel „00“ bei Anrufen von Europa in das Ausland oder „011“ bei Anrufen von Nordamerika in das Ausland."

Comment: @scienceponder Nicht, wenn du vom Handy anrufst. Am Handy kannst du auch + wählen. Mein Einwand war aber hauptsächlich, dass 0049 vom Festnetz aus auch nicht unbedingt funktioniert.

Comment: @jarnbjo Ja klar. Wie gesagt, das ist ein Platzhalter. Der Anrufer muss selbst entscheiden *ob* er diesen ersetz und wenn ja durch was.

Comment: Warum nicht einfach einen regulären Ausdruck angeben? `((\+49)|0)511 12387654` :-)

Comment: Inwiefern ist das eine Frage, die mit der deutschen Sprache zu tun hat? Hat nicht jemand, der in Spanien eine spanische Visitenkarte gestalten will dasselbe Problem? Oder jemand in Russland mit russischen Visitenkarten? Dies hier ist Forum, das Fragen zur deutschen Sprache zum Inhalt hat. Ich glaube, dass Fragen zur Typographie insbesondere dann off-Topic sind, wenn man dieselben Probleme auch in anderen Sprachen hat.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich habe die Frage auch erst für off-topic gehalten, dann aber ein bisschen geforscht und festgestellt, dass die Angabe der Null in Klammern anscheinend eine zum Glück aussterbende (Un)sitte in D und A ist. Deswegen irgendwie zumindestens nicht ganz off-topic.

Comment: Das ist keine Frage über Sprache, sondern eine nach der richtigen Verwendung eines Leerzeichens in der Schreibung von Telefonnummern. Als typografische Frage sollte sie in *Graphic Design* stehen. Man könnte sagen, die Frage gehöre hierher, da sie speziell auf deutsche Gepflogenheiten abzielt, aber es handelt sich um eine Frage der Ästhetik, die auch von einem amerikanischen Designer beantwortet werden könnte. Es geht ja explizit nicht darum, die 0 wegzulassen, und selbst das wäre nicht Deutsch.

Answer (score 9):

Das ist an sich keine Rechtschreib- oder Typographiefrage und an sich auch keine speziell deutsche Geschichte.

Das Format wie nationale und internationale Telefonrufnummern geschrieben werden sollen, ist von der ITU (der internationalen Fernmeldeunion) standardisiert. Der passende Standard dazu heißt [E.123](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.123). Die DIN-Norm hat dort (auch naheliegend und vollkommen legitim) wohl abgeschrieben.

Dieser Standard sieht keine "Klammernull" vor. Ich persönlich finde diese Schreibweise auch eher irreführend, und würde entweder die Rufnummer als "internationale" oder als "nationale" angeben, anstatt beide Formate in ein (missverständliches) Format zu pressen. Die Schreibweise  so wie du sie angibst, impliziert für mich, als ob man immer die Landesvorwahl wählen sollte (die steht nicht in Klammern) und die Null nach Lust und Laune weglassen könnte (weil die in Klammern steht) - Das ist natürlich falsch, vollkommen unabhängig davon, ob man noch irgendwo ein Leerzeichen reinpresst.

Die Klammern sind auch deswegen irreführend, weil dieser internationale Standard sie schon verwendet, um bei einer nationalen Rufnummer die Vorwahl (ONKZ) zu kennzeichnen.

(Du kannst ja auch mal, nur um die "Praktikabilität" zu testen, spasseshalber versuchen, so eine Nummer, von mir aus ohne oder mit Leerzeichen, in dein Handy einzugeben - Viel Glück wirst du damit nicht haben. Das schließt natürlich so ein Format vom automatischen Wählen mit Handy und Computer oder copy & paste, z.B. von einer Webseite, schonmal aus. Daher m.A. nach absolut keine gute Idee)

Es handelt sich bei dieser geklammerten Null anscheinend um eine rein deutschsprachige (Un)Sitte, die laut [Wikipedia (Erste Tabelle, letzte Zeile](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rufnummer)) in D und A verbreitet sei (was ich anzweifle, auch der dort angegebene Verweis führt nicht auf eine Seite, die das untermauern würde), womit wir dann wieder einigermassen on-topic wären. Ich bin mir allerdings nicht bewusst, irgendwann in neuerer Zeit noch so ein Format mit einer Null in Klammern gesehen zu haben. Diese Unsitte scheint also aus naheliegenden Gründen auszusterben - Es ist also einigermaßen müßig, sich für eine an sich falsche Darstellung eine "schöne Typografie" suchen zu wollen.

Comment: Das sind interessante Gedanken. Die Frage ist aber nicht, ob man die Null nicht ganz weglassen sollte (das will nicht mal die Visitenkartenabteilung), sondern ob da ein Spatium hingehört oder nicht. Aber ich gehe dem E.123 mal nach...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Wenn da keine Null hingehört (wie ich finde), erübrigt sich die Frage nach dem typografischen Leerraum. Sorum wird ein Schuh draus. Ansonsten läuft deine Frage auf "Ich möchte etwas falsch machen. Wie mache ich das möglichst richtig?" hinaus.

Answer (score 2):

> Andererseits ist die Klammernull so unüblich nicht. Gerade Leute, die sowohl mit in- wie mit ausländischen Geschäftspartnern zu tun haben, verwenden sie gerne, um einerseits die volle Nummer samt Landesvorwahl abgebildet zu haben, andererseits die inländischen Partner daran zu erinnern, beim Weglassen der Landesvorwahl dann eine Null für die Ortsnetzvorwahl vorzuwählen.

Bei diesen Hinweisen auf die Internationalität von Geschäftspartnern möge man die Sprachversion des folgenden Zitats bitte verzeihen:

> When conducting business, e.g., for display on business cards or stationery, the number should be written as +61 7 3333 3333, and **include only the digits that must be dialed from internationally.** The plus sign is used to indicate that an international trunk prefix is first dialed and, therefore, a country code then follows. **It has become common *(but incorrect)* practice to write the number with the national trunk prefix in parentheses, for example: +61 (0) 7 3333 3333. However, someone calling this number from the U.S. may mistake the national trunk code for a single-digit area code, as NANP area codes are often written in parentheses, dial all the digits and result in a failed call.** ITU-T Recommendation E.123 states that parentheses should not be used in the international notation.
>   <sub>[WP: Trunk-prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trunk_prefix)</sub>

Da die angesprochene Norm schon [bei @tofro verhandelt](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/47615/29694) wurde, möchte ich mich seiner Antwort anschließen und zum Widerstand aufrufen gegen die "regelgläubigen Bürokratie", die anscheinend trotz [klarer Regeln](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers#Germany) hierzu ein [cornflower blue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUoKrdB9BjU) durchsetzen will für eine überflüssige Null.

Eine beispielsweise "wohlgesetzte" +496151345312 kann man so in sein Handy eingeben, wählen und die gewünschte Nummer erreichen; inklusive, wenn nicht gar bevorzugt, mit dem Pluszeichen –– und [das weltweit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verkehrsausscheidungsziffer#International)! Mit einer +4906151345312 kommt man einfach nicht durch.

---

<sub>Das Bedürfnis in der Telefonnummer eine Klammernull unterbringen zu wollen schient mir vor allem aus einer Fehlinterpretation zu stammen. Zum Beispiel aus der von Microsofft stammenden Vorgabe für</sub>

> <sub>[Canonical Addresses](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Tapi/address-ovr#canonical_addresses)
>   The canonical address format is intended to be a universally constant directory number. For this reason, numbers in address books are best stored using canonical format.
>   The following details concern what is considered canonical for a phone address.
>   A canonical phone address is a text string with the following structure:</sub>
>
>   
>     <sub>+ CountryCode Space [**(AreaCode)** Space] SubscriberNumber | Subaddress ^ Name CRLF ...</sub>

<sub>Nur sieht das Resultat dann so aus:</sub>

> [+1 (425) 555-1212](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-at/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc772545(v=ws.10))

<sub>Und berücksichtigt also nicht die in Deutschland benötigte 0. Vermutlich handelt es sich bei dem Wunsch nach der Klammernull um einen falsch verstandenen Internationalismus?</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Wenn die Angabe mit +49 erfolgt, sollte man mE die 0 ganz weglassen.

> +49 511 123 87 654

Den Rest mit Spatien, oder meinetwegen Leerzeichen, sinnvoll gruppieren. Meine Handynummer gebe ich zB regelmäßig als +43664 xx xx xxx an.

Answer (score 1):

Forssman und de Jong bieten in *Detailtypografie* (S. 197) im Wesentlichen zwei Möglichkeiten:

1. die Nummer an den Bruchstellen zwischen Ländervorwahl, Ortsvorwahl und der eigentlichen Telefonnummer nur durch die Satzzeichen `()–/.|` und / oder Wortzwischenräume zu trennen:

   > 0511 12387654
   >
   > +49 511 12387654
   >
   > (+49) (511) 12387654
   >
   > +49.511.12387654
   >
   > ...
2. oder die gesamte Telefonnummer von **hinten nach vorn** zusätzlich mit geschützten flexiblen Leerzeichen oder geschützten Wortzwischenräumen in Zweiergrüppchen zu trennen:

   > (05 11) 12 38 76 54
   >
   > +49 5 11 12 38 76 54
   >
   > (+49) (5 11) 12 38 76 54
   >
   > +49 | 5 11 | 12 38 76 54
   >   ...

In Variante 1 sind längere Nummern schwieriger zu erfassen, Variante 2 ist unruhiger.

In allen (zahlreichen) Beispielen im Buch wird die führende Null der Ortsvorwahl weggelassen, wenn die internationale Vorwahl vor der Nummer steht.

Diese Null in Klammern mitzuschreiben kann jedoch sinnvoll sein:
Die in Deutschland geltende Regel, die Null nicht zu wählen, wenn man den Ländercode wählt, gilt nicht für alle Länder.
Beispielsweise muss bei italienischen Festnetznummern die führende Null der Ortsvorwahl auch dann mitgewählt werden, wenn man die Nummer inklusive des Ländercodes +39 anwählt.

Generell würde ich die Nummer so einfach und gleichzeitig so lesbar wie möglich schreiben. Wie einfach es sein darf, hängt davon ab, an wen ich mich dabei richte:
Ist die internationale Vorwahl überhaupt notwendig?

Zur Lesbarkeit können auch Mediävalziffern beitragen, die aber nicht in jedem Schriftsatz vorhanden sind und nicht zu jedem Design passen.
Der Nummer genug Raum zu geben und sie ausreichend groß zu setzen hilft ebenfalls.

Comment: Das Problem existiert also gar nicht in/für Italien, da die 0 dort obligatorisch ist, und daher also niemals in Klammern steht?

Comment: Die "italienische Ausnahme" ist hier irrelevant und kann höchstens zur Verwirrung beitragen - Es wird nach *deutschen Telefonnummern* gefragt.

Comment: Die Varianten (1) + (2) sind, sofern man Leerzeichen verwendet, durch die E.123 abgedeckt. Varianten mit "irgendwelchen" anderen Sonderzeichen zur Trennung der Nummernbestandteile lassen vollkommen außer acht, dass man z.B. mit Copy & Paste aus einer Webseite heraus wählen wollte, was heutzutage nicht mehr sooo ungewöhnlich ist. Das geht dann nämlich nicht, bzw. das Telefon erkennt die Zeichen nicht als Rufnummer.

Comment: @tofro Dass man die Null überhaupt in Klammern schreibt, liegt eben genau darin begründet, dass die Standards nicht weltweit gleich sind. Gäbe es diese Abweichungen nicht, gäbe es für diese Schreibung keinen Grund. Und für Personen aus Ländern, deren Rufnummern nicht diesem „Standard“ entsprechen, *kann die Null in Klamm wichtig sein*. Wenn es nur um deutsche Anrufer auf deutsche Nummern ginge, bestünde die Problematik nicht.

Comment: @tofro Ich kenne die technischen Normen nicht und weiß nicht, ob es sie überhaupt gibt. Vielleicht abhängig vom Dialer? Wenn ich mit meinem Telefon (Android 8.1) eine Telefonnummer mit Sonderzeichen (gerade auf Handynummer mit +49 und / probiert) anrufe, werden diese automatisch entfernt.

Comment: Mit "Sonderzeichen" war hauptsächlich das letzte Beispiel mit den senkrechten Strichen gemeint. Die "verdaut" mein Telefon nicht. Auf "/" scheint es tatsächlich eingerichtet zu sein.

Comment: @tofro Ich muss einräumen, dass es bei *Detailtypografie* um Drucksachen, nicht um Webtypografie geht. Insofern muss man zur Verteidigung des Werks sagen, dass sie solche Empfehlungen nicht für Webseiten aussprechen. Visitenkarten sind aber eine Drucksache.

Comment: Es wird explizit nach einem Argument „zur Verteidigung einer brauchbaren Typographie gegenüber einer regelgläubigen Bürokratie“ in Bezug auf die Telefonnummer auf Visitenkarten gefragt. *Detailtypografie* ist **das** Nachschlagewerk zu Fragen deutscher Typografie. Wenn die Visitenkartenabteilung das nicht zumindest in Betracht zieht, haben sie keine gelernten Mediengestalter.

Comment: Ein Buch über Typografie, das das wichtigste textuelle Kommunikationsmittel des 21. Jahrhunderts nicht zur Kenntnis nimmt, ist ein bißchen anachronistisch, oder? Und Rufnummern, die auf der Webseite anders angezeigt werden als auf  der Visitenkarte, sind ein bisschen doof. Außerdem gibt's ja auch sowas: http://www.spiegel.de/netzwelt/gadgets/visitenkarten-scanner-nie-wieder-adressen-abschreiben-a-699856.html

Comment: @tofro jetzt wird es aber wild :) Nein, das ist nicht anachronistisch. Webtypo ist einfach ein völlig anderes Thema mit ganz anderen Parametern. Dafür gibt es andere Quellen, und damit beschäftigen sich andere Leute. Ein Visitenkartenscanner ist eine spezielle OCR-Anwendung, die solche Probleme lösen muss das ist aber nicht das Problem des Typografen.

Answer (score 0):

Als Beispiel: +49 6151 3453-12

Jeder in der Welt kann überall +496151345312 eintippen und kommt richtig an.

Deutsche in Deutschland sollten die Regeln kennen, dass +49 die Vorwahl für Deutschland ist, und dass man in Deutschland eine 0 einfügt, also 06151345312. Ausländer in Deutschland kennen vielleicht die Regeln nicht, aber +496151345312 funktioniert auch in Deutschland.

Wenn eine 0 eingefügt wird, also +49 (0) 6151 3453-12, das hilft niemandem und kann nur zur Verwirrung führen.

Comment: Stimme zwar zu (s. meine Antwort ;) ) aber: Bei analog designten Telefonen geht das nicht. Diese Regel ist nur für Mobiltelefone gültig (& ähnlich neumodisches Zeugs)? Bitte näher erklären. [Auf meinem drei Jahre alten HDphone an VOIP ist kein +-Zeichen sichtbar…]

Answer (score -1):

Die Null sollte man in der Klammer nicht weglassen! Diese Information ist sehr wichtig, denn es gibt einige (afrikanische) Länder, bei denen man die NULL sehr wohl mitwählen muss.
Wenn man aus einem solchen Land kommt, ist es hilfreich, die (0) zu sehen. 
Mir hilft das im Ausland sehr, wenn ich diese Zusatzinformation erhalte.

Comment: Könntest du uns ein afrikanisches Land nennen, aus dem heraus Richtung Deutschland nach der Landesvorwahl auch die Null gewählt werden muss?

Comment: @Pollitzer Angeblich ist das auch in Italien der Fall, und das liegt nicht einmal in Afrika. Vgl. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telefonvorwahl_(Italien)

Comment: @Philipp: Über Telefonate nach Deutschland sagt die verlinkte Seite nichts aus.

Comment: @Pollitzer Nein, das wollte ich auch nicht sagen. Ich meinte: Wenn man (egal ob aus Italien oder einem anderen Land) italienische Festnetznummern mit Ländercode anruft, kann die führende Null nicht entfallen. Daher: Es kann sinnvoll sein, die Null in Klammern zu belassen, damit (z. B.) ein Italiener weiß, dass sie weggelassen wird, wenn die +49 gewählt wird, dass sie aber gewählt werden muss, wenn die Nummer aus Deutschland ohne +49 gewählt wird. Ich denke, so ist auch die Antwort gemeint.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass es Länder gibt, von denen aus man eine deutsche Nummer mit +49 **und** der führenden 0 der Ortsvorwahl anwählen muss oder überhaupt kann.

Comment: @Philipp: Das glaube ich auch nicht; trotzdem hätte ich gern eine klare Auskunft von der Antwortgeberin.

Answer (score -2):

Dass es nicht praktiziert wird (daher auch keiner Regel entsprechen dürfte), ist mir bewusst, aber am einleuchtendsten erscheint mir die Notation

> +49/0 6151 3453-12

da entweder »+49« vorgewählt wird oder »0.«

Bei der Klammernull kommt der Laie ins Grübeln; die Aussage, bei Einsatz der Null »+49« wegzulassen, liegt bei dieser Notation nicht auf der Hand.

Comment: Man soll doch nicht durch 0 dividieren!

Comment: Ich finde die Schreibung +49 (0)511 123-87654 nicht so unlogisch: Die Null ist weggeklammert, weil man sie wegzulassen hat, wenn man etwas anderes noch vorwählt, aber sie ist sichtbar für den Fall, dass man bei ihr zu wählen anfängt... Oder wenn nicht logisch, dann ist es doch ein guter Kompromiss zwischen Ästhetik und Praktischsein.

Comment: Ich finde dieses Format mit der Klammernull vollkommen unlogisch:  Ein Teil, der optional ist, wird mit einer Klammer markiert, ein anderer Teil, der es zumindestens für nationale Gespräche auch ist, eben nicht.

Comment: Einleuchtend ist definitiv anders :-) Bei dieser Schreibweise wüsste ich überhaupt nicht mehr was ich wählen soll, wenn ich nicht mit der Materie vertraut wäre.

Comment: ... und wer mit der Materie vertraut ist, braucht die (0) eigentlich gar nicht.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Dann ist bei Inlandsgesprächen aber der Tippaufwand größer.